# setinterval Stops Working After 540 seconds (time limit in Firebase hosting), How to Solve this?

Tags: node.js, firebase, setinterval, firebase-hosting

I've been using NodeJS running on Firebase hosting to monitor sensor values
(through dedicated hardware). I simply use function setinterval to check 
the sensor values via API that I wrote. The system reads from sensor 
successfully for every minutes (for just testing) but it stops reading 
after 9 minutes (or 540 seconds according to google document [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) ??). The reading sensor function is working, only the loop in setinterval that stops working as I've mentioned. My simple code looks like this:

```
var intervalObj = setinterval(function(sensor_id){
      var val = readSensorValue(sensor_id);    
      var d = new Date();
      console.log("reading from sensor[" + sensor_id + "] => " + val + "@" + d);
   }, 60000);
```

However, I have to monitor the sensor all day long. How can I fix this??
Or there's any other better approach??

Thank you for your time,

JJ

:D:D:D

Comment: Set a higher level variable to track each 9min interval? Just do the math after the fact? If your just looking for a work around...

Comment: Why don't you set a cron job to call your script instead of keeping it running and relying on `setInterval()`?

Comment: I've been working on cron job... thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: well, the cron package from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) is doing the same thing. it stops looping after 540 seconds. I have no clue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided not to use Firebase function hosting for now, so I run the project on the VM and everything's been working fine. Just a simple setInterval... even though I'm still wonder whether it is a design by Firebase for such limitation or there should be other approach for doing this on Firebase.

Thanks for all the comment. 
:D:D:D